# How to get famo.us/angularjs element from html as famo.us constructed object in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, famo.us

There's an html famo.us/Angular scrollview object code in html like this

```
    <fa-scroll-view>
              content
    </fa-scroll-view>
```

i want to get the scrollview as famo.us Scrollview object like it's made with "new Scrollview()" in the controller to control it...thank you in advance.

i heard about something called $famous.find but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add an identifier to the HTML:

HTML

```
<fa-scroll-view id="myId">
    content
</fa-scroll-view>
```

Depending on where you're using the reference (i.e. Angular controller, directive, etc), you will have to inject the `$famousProvider` and then you can retrieve the javascript object using the find function.  If you're trying to use the object in a controller, you could declare the controller like this:

JS

```
...
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$famousProvider',function($famousProvider){

    var scrollView = $famousProvider.find("#myId");
    ...
})
...
```

This of course assumes you have declared your angular application and added a reference to the famo.us library already.  Also, the famo.us docs are not that clear in terms of what format the selector looks like.  Therefore, if the find with `"#myId"` doesn't work, try just using `"myId"`

Comment: It gives me error for an anonymous injector $famousProvider, in the famous.js the docs say @name $famousProvider but the directive name is just $famous, here : https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular/blob/master/src/scripts/services/famous.js 
if you've a modified file version or something please tell me where can i find it...thank you.

Comment: Their docs were incorrect. You should use $famous in the places where $famousProvider are indicated above. Or if you tried this already, are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, i tried $famous too, it retrieves undefined!! i tried class instead of id and tried to remove the dot or hash symbol but the same error, undefined!! 
the description from their docs : 
View:
   * ```html
   * <fa-scroll-view id="myScrollView"></fa-scroll-view>
   * ```
   * Controller:
   * ```javascript
   * var scrollViewReference = $famous.find('#myScrollView')[0].renderNode;
   * //Now scrollViewReference is pointing to the Famo.us Scrollview object
   * //that we created in the view.

Comment: $famous.find worked with me, i just had to put the line in the $http.success in order to see the fa-scroll-view...thank you very much.

Comment: as @MohamedSeif said, you have to wait for everything to be loaded before trying to find the element. So you could find it in some callback or just set a timeout of a couple seconds and then it will be there